# Evitar posibles bloqueos por parte del informe tsql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, tsql, bloqueo

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado para obtener un informe complejo, y quiero evitar bloqueos o al menos que se ejecute con menos prioridad (eso creo que sólo estaba en ORACLE en su momento, y no en SQL SERVER si no me equivoco).

Encontré algo así:

```
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON
      SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED           -- Para evitar posibles bloqueos por parte del informe
```

Otras veces veo que se puede utilizar **NO LOCK**.

cuál es la recomendación para evitar bloqueos al ejecutar un informe?

Comment: La recomendación es usar `Set Transaction` [set transaction vs nolock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550337/with-nolock-vs-set-transaction-isolation-level-read-uncommitted), pero eso te devuelve lecturas sucias. No es algo considerado como una buena práctica. Siempre hay que tenerlo en cuenta.

Comment: ¿cuánto tarda la ejecución del SP? ¿Qué problema específico te producen los bloqueos que genera? ¿Hace solamente lectura de información, es decir, solo sentencias `select`?

Answer (score 2):

La recomendación es no usar ninguna de las opciones que mencionas. Ambas opciones hacen exactamente lo mismo aunque no sea inmediatamente obvio. Lo que obtienes con eso es que el proceso que estás realizando pueda leer cambios que aun no han sido completados. Esto te puede generar datos faltantes, duplicados o que por alguna razón no fueron permanentes.

Aun más importante es el hecho de que esa solución sigue generando bloqueos porque asigna un `LOCK` compartido que permite que otros lean pero no que lo modifiquen.

Para solucionar este problema, es importante diseñar los índices correctamente para que las consultas puedan bloquear la menor cantidad de filas posibles.

También es posible usar niveles de aislamiento optimistas como `SNAPSHOT` y `READ COMMITED SNAPSHOT`. Sin embargo, esta solución no es gratuita ya que genera una mayor carga en la base de datos tempdb por tener que crear copias de la información.

En conclusión, no existe una fórmula mágica para eliminar los bloqueos. Son una herramienta importante para proteger la información. Lo que realmente tienes que hacer es optimizar las consultas y el diseño de índices.